# How do I get an asynchronous TCP object stream in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp

I'm pretty new to serialization so please bear with me.

I want two instances of my application to communicate with each other over the internet.  I have successfully rigged up a TCP client/server relationship and used a binary formatter to get the two sides to swap a single pair of messages.  Here's the client side...

```
using (TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(ipAddress, currentPort))
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = clientSocket.GetStream())
    {
        // send
        bformatter.Serialize(stream, new Message());

        // recv
        return (Message)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

It's cool, but not very useful for an application that needs to send messages in response to user events.  So I need to be able to send and receive asynchronously.

I basically want an interface that behaves like this:

```
class BidirectionalObjectStream
{
    public BidirectionalObjectStream(TcpClient client)
    {
        //...
    }

    // objects go in here
    public void SendObject(object o)
    {
        //...
    }

    // objects come out here
    public event Action<object> ObjectReceived;
}
```

Is there a class like this that's part of .NET?  If not, how should I implement the receive event?  Maybe a dedicated thread calling `bformatter.Deserialize()` repeatedly...?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "used a binary formatter" Don't do this unless you 100% trust your communication partner. `BinaryFormatter` allows low level access to fields and thus most likely allows arbitrary code execute in the context of your program for the sender of a message. Consider using json or protobuf for your messages.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little broad.

I can think of two options:

- Use asynchronous socket. [Using an Asynchronous Client Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx)
- Create separate threads for receiving and sending. There many ways to achieve it, raw Thread, ThreadPool, delegate.Invoke, new TPL features like Task and Parallel.